# Use of Ember.$.proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have the following code;

```
eventsToListen: function() {
    var self=this;
    return [{
        eventName: "Submit",
        callBack: Ember.$.proxy(this.clearFunction, this)
    }];
},
```

I wanted to understand what does the line "Ember.$.proxy" signify ?

Is that a jquery method ?

Comment: This is to bind cantext to correct context. Read this first: [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: `Ember.$` is just jquery, `Ember.$.proxy` is the same as [$.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)